# What the Regex?

Tags: regex

Can anyone tell me what this bit of regex does?

```
</?[a-z0-9-=""'!\$\?%&\*\+@~##;,\\]*:[a-z0-9 -=""'!\$\?%&\*\+@~##;,\\]*>
```

My regex is not the best.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It matches sgml elements with namespace (start tags and end tags). Please note that this regex also matches elements without a name and/or namespace. But this regex will never match empty tags.

Will match:
`<:>`,
`</:>`,
`<abc:abc019>`

Will not match
`<hello>`,
`</abc>`,
`<abc:abc019 />`,
`<abc />`

Answer (score 0):

Finds a `<`, an optional `/`, zero or more of a bunch of characters, a `:`, zero or more of a bunch of characters, and a `>`.

Comment: A little less abstractly, it's likely intended to locate opening and closing XML tags which are all explicitly namespaced.